# Why are most lyrics translations so bad?

Tags: lyrics

I've been looking at the national anthem of the Soviet Union, and I've found several translations. Only [one of them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2jnX2y30DE), however, fits the rhyme and meter of the song. Others, such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sxTbfeYdO0), only make a weak attempt at following the rhyme and meter (the one linked falls apart after the third line). Is there a reason for this, or is it just that the people who write translations in subtitles (translations that are sun are generally good for obvious reasons) are lazy?

Comment: "Translation is like a woman. If it is beautiful, it is not faithful. If it is faithful, it is most certainly not beautiful." Yevgeny Yevtushenko

Answer (score 3):

It's notoriously difficult to translate poetry, which is what most song lyrics are.  Poetry is an interface between the actual sound of the words and the meaning.  Since each language has its own rhythm and phonemes, recapturing the magic of the original can be an impossibility.

The best case scenario for translation is to find someone who is fluent in both languages, and also a gifted poet (or in this case, songwriter) in their own right.  That is rare.

The more common case is for either the meaning or the sound (meter and rhyme scheme) to be neglected.  In the former case, you end up with a new song to the old melody.  In the latter case, you get a prose translation.